# Highcharts Pie Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

My code is here

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                 {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
             {
                name: 'FireFox',
                y: 15.8
                                }
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

In ToolTip

```
tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        }
```

I want to write

```
tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.data.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        }
```

its Not Working please some one help me

I am following this link

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

Comment: Can you throw your own code in a jsfiddle, because i have no clue what is going wrong on your end now.

Comment: Sir this is my own code but name is different only

Comment: what you want to show on tooltip?

Comment: Allright, i think that is because data is an array, so if you say series.data.name, it does not know which data object is needed. If you for example would say series.data[0].name it would always returns chrome. Calling series.data.name can either be firefox or chrome

Comment: Names like Chrome,Firefox but not Browser share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `point.name` should help

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/tMqT3/)**

```
 tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

I adivce you to use formatter, which allows to customise content. Custom parameter will be kept in point.options.name

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter